# Whose names were written in the Governor's notebook?

Tags: tv, the-walking-dead

On *The Walking Dead*, in the episode *Say the Word* (Season 2 Episode 5), Michonne sneaks into the Governor's office and finds the following list of names written in a notebook, with his daughter's name listed last:

[image]

Whose names are these, who wrote them, and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [*The Walking Dead* Wikia](https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Say_the_Word):

> The Governor's list that Michonne stumbles upon contains **the names of several key characters in *The Walking Dead: Rise of the Governor* novel**. The first three show the names of Brian, Bobby, and Nick, as well as the last name on the list of Penny. This suggests the TV Series is at least partially following the canon history of The Governor established in the Novel Series. This is further backed up by Morrissey stating that he read *Rise of The Governor* whilst preparing for the role.

Based on this, it would appear that **Bobby** (second name in list) refers to [Bobby Marsh](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Bobby_Marsh) and that **Nick** (third name) refers to [Nick Parsons](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Nick_Parsons).  **Brian** (the very first name) mostly likely refers to The Governor himself, i.e. [Brian Blake](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Brian_Blake_(Comic_Series)).

As for who wrote these names and why, I would imagine that either The Governor himself or his daughter Penny wrote them and that they are the names of dead people, in chronological order, with Penny being the last entry.  It could be that Penny maintained the list and, after her death, The Governor ended it by writing in her name and blocking off the rest of the page.

Note that while The Governor himself is not dead, his previous identity of "Brian" is dead in a sense, as he replaced it with *Philip Blake*, a persona that he felt was more suitable for their unforgiving world.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. What about the tally marks though?

Comment: @S.Fruggiero : Not sure, but I think it might be counting something --- perhaps the number of days Penny has been a Walker.

Comment: Also, apparently the Governor doesn't know how to spell "Keith".

Comment: @Praxis:   It can't be the number of days.  It's too tally marks.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Fair enough.  It could just be the scratchings of a mad man.  The OP only asked about the names (not the scratchings), so I'll leave my speculations on the marks off to the side.... :-)

Answer (score -1):

I recently won this notebook at an auction, along with the Gov's watch and a few other possessions. I don't think the Brian refers to the Gov himself because he picks the name Brian after seeing it written on a barn in S4. The slash marks were explained by Greg Nicotero on Talking Dead. He says they don't mean anything, other than to show the Governor was kind of losing his mind. The notebook also has several pages of writing on shown on screen.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So whose names were those then?  Please make sure that if you're posting an answer you're actually answering the question.  When you earn some reputation you'll be able to leave comments; in the meantime you might want to take the [tour].

Comment: Well, I believe I did address the 'Brian' name, stating it wasn't likely referring to himself, as another poster had speculated. As for who all the other names are....perhaps only The Gov himself can tell us :)

Comment: If you're replying to the other answer that identifies Brian, then you're really just commenting on that answer instead of posting a proper answer of your own.  Your answer should completely answer the question; imagine that the other answer isn't there at all, and ask if your answer stands on its own.

Comment: LOL, this is one of the most pointless discussions I've had on the internet in awhile. I think you could handle some advice yourself, son. :) Try making the place more welcoming to new members instead of aiming for a Guinness World Record in pedantics. ;)

Comment: Anyway, the notebook is an interesting read. :) ;).